# Variable in Where Clause in Axapta

Tags: axapta, x++

I have an update statement in a Job in axapta and I want to use a variable inside of the updates where clause

```
static void UpdateSomeValues(Args _args)
{
    Table myTable;
    str likeThis;
    ;

    likeThis = 'W200';

    ttsBegin;
    select forUpdate myTable
    where myTable.start == 'W100'
    && myTable.destination like likeThis;

    myTable.AlloweMove = NoYes::Yes;
    myTable.AllowStop = NoYes::Yes;

    ttsCommit;
}
```

The error I get is translated something like this:

*unbound Strings are not allowed in the where clause*

Is there a workaround to use Strings in the where clause in x++ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There error occurs because the string has an infinite length. Try using an appropriate EDT or something like `str 50 likeThis;`

```
static void UpdateSomeValues(Args _args)
{
    Table myTable;
    str 50 likeThis;
    ;

    likeThis = 'W200';

    ttsBegin;
    select forUpdate myTable
    where myTable.start == 'W100'
    && myTable.destination like likeThis;

    myTable.AlloweMove = NoYes::Yes;
    myTable.AllowStop = NoYes::Yes;

    ttsCommit;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a workaround to use Strings in the where clause in x++ ?

Yes, you have to use a bounded string, which is a string of a defined maximum length. This is why usually an extended data type is used as the data type of variables, because the extended data type properties already define the maximum length. But if you can't use an exteneded data type, you can also set the maximum length of a string variable like so:

```
str 4 likeThis;
;

likeThis = 'W200';
```

The number after `str` defines the maximum length of the variable. This variable can then be used in the where clause of a select Statement.

Also take a look at [Strings [AX 2012]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa889472.aspx)